# How to fix server error 500 web api in mobile app

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, mobile

I have ASP.NET WEB API project that allows a user to upload images, then these images are viewed in another page. 
The images are uploaded successfully; however, some of these images return **SERVER ERROR 500** when the GET method is called from a mobile app.

If I copy the url that returns the error and perform the request from the browser or postman the url works correctly so the images are found in the server.
What could be the cause that the url is not working only on mobile?

Here is the code that returns the image:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Stores/{id}/Photos/{pid}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetStorePhoto(int id, int pid)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var photo = store.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == pid);
            if (photo == null)
                return ImageNotFound();  //returns a default image in case image not found

            var filePath =
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Stores/" + photo.FileName);

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                return ImageNotFound();
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your server log say? In most cases, the error will be printed out there.

Comment: the error only says '500 Internal Server Error'

Comment: Could you show us your code that is responsible for returning the image?

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Have you tried to use Visual Studio's _break points_ to verify the output?

Comment: yes I have, I can as well test the output from PostMan or any browser and it works.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know the problem then.. :/ Perhaps extending your logs could provide more information. So on every request, write some data to a file which can confirm that the image was found and loaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on the getRequest I was trying to access the same folder twice at the same to get the width and height of the photo. After I deleted that code, the error was fixed.
Here's the code that I was calling before getting the image:

```
            foreach (var photo in Photos)
            {
                try
                {
                    Image img = Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Stores/" + photo.FileName));
                    var sizedImage = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    photo.Height = sizedImage.Height;
                    photo.Width = sizedImage.Width;

                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

Thanks !